# Can't modify the app menu in Electron app

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I know it works, I just did it a few weeks ago but now it say this when i try doing it. and also its put in another file named menu.js.

[LOG]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined
  at menu.js:36
```

[line 36]

```
app.isReady().then(t => {
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(temp)
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
    createWindow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing this import, because your `app` is `undefined`:

```js
const { app } =  require('electron');
```

Also `isReady` method returns a boolean (`true/false`) not a `Promise`. You are looking for `app.whenReady()` method, something like this:

```js
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow(...options...)
  // create and load window procedure...

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(temp)
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```